# Change CSV Delimiter in ORDS

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-ords

I've recently setup Oracle Rest Data Services (ORDS) and managed to successfully create several endpoints returning both JSON and CSV data. However, is there was a way to change the delimiter (such as to a tab or pipe) on `csv/query` services? Since the ORDS packages are encrypted, there's no way to do modifications on that front, and none of the documentation I've read suggests there's a built in option to make this change.

I'm considering creating an plugin into ORDS that would basically call the CSV path and then convert it to the new delimiter before returning the data, but before that I wanted to make sure there wasn't any easier way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Was this solved?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Developing Oracle Rest Data Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e56293/develop.htm#AELIG90005)

Pattern: **POST** http://< HOST>:< PORT >/ords/< SchemaAlias>/< ObjectAlias>/batchload?< Parameters>

One parameter is: delimiter

"Sets the field delimiter for the fields in the file. The default is the comma (,)."

Comment: Isn't the question about a get-call - to get data out of the db - and not about a post-call?

Comment: POST/GET- worked the same with both. I use POST a lot to get data out. Especially if I do not want the data criteria saved in access logs.

Comment: I'm not so sure this really works for GET! See this discussion here:  https://community.oracle.com/message/15542725#15542725